# &thinsp;, &ensp;, &emsp; alternatives in Safari browser

Tags: html, safari

&thinsp;, &ensp;, &emsp; are broken in Safari browser.

[image: spaces]

These are thin space, n-size space, m-size space which works in other browsers.

thinsp : a b c d e f g

ensp : a b c d e f g

emsp : a b c d e f g

Are there alternatives for these in Safari?

Comment: just count the number of spaces and use the normal nbsp?

Comment: @Steve thinsp is thinner than nbsp (non-breaking space). And double spaces are not parsed as double spaces in a browser.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This could be a font problem; it might help to specify a font that contains glyphs for the fixed-width spaces used. Most fonts lack them. Good browsers don’t need the glyphs but instead increase spacing between other characters.

However, a more robust approach is to use CSS techniques for adding spacing, mainly the `padding` properties and, for runs of text where specific spacing is desired between all letters, the `letter-spacing` property. Using the latter, note that it adds spacing after the last character, too. My page on [Unicode spaces](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) shows the defined or typical widths of “fixed-width spaces” like THIN SPACE (which aren’t all really fixed-width). But it is probably better to start from the amount of desired spacing, in terms of the `em` unit (font size), and just forget the fixed-width spaces.

Yet another possibility is to use the normal SPACE character but wrap it in a `span` and set its width. This requires making it an inline block. The approach is better than the above when the desired non-CSS fallback is a regular space rather than lack of any spacing. Note that search engines should be assumed CSS-ignorant, so this approach is relevant to making them “see” a word space between characters (e.g. to see “foo bar” and not “foo bar” when you want a fixed-width space between the words “foo” and “bar”). And as usual, you can use NO-BREAK SPACE instead of SPACE in order to prevent line break.

Example:

```css
.thin {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<div style="font-size: 200%">
<div>a b (normal space)</div>
<div>a&thinsp;b (thin space)</div>
<div><span style="padding-right: 0.2em">a</span>b (0.2em padding)</div>
<div><span style="letter-spacing: 0.2em">ab</span> (0.2em letter spacing)</div>
<div>a<span class=thin> </span>b (space set to 0.2em width)</div>
<div>a<span class=thin>&nbsp;</span>b (no-break space set to 0.2em width)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm.. I hope that Safari would support these things. (and other features also.) Safari is bad in comparison to other browsers, in many features (specially in scalability or responsible web).

Answer (score 3):

This problem seems to be fixed. I cannot reproduce it, anyhow. I tested with four common fonts. Here's the test page:

http://burtonsys.com/test_html_spaces.html

I don't have an Apple device, but I used a couple of cross-browser testing web sites to check it with Safari. All the space characters seem to work fine, both in Safari 9.1.3, and in Safari 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to align boxes in a form and used `&nbsp` in a `span` using `style="padding-left: 0.7em` before the input element. I then adjusted each em to align the boxes using `0.4em`, `0.85em`, `0.95em` and `1.3em` which all lined up against the input box that did not require any adjustment.

Comment: aligning boxes using gliphs is the same error that some peaple do when they want to build columns in WORD with spaces...